# Youtube API - Video is not available

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any way to detect if a video was removed or unavailable? 
We need to have ability to remove it from the video listing if it has been removed from youtube server.

Answer (score 0):

Hung BUI if you are using youtube API there is a way to filter the video which has been removed or not availble in your locality.

Kindly watch this video and seek it to 2m:03s, The tutor will say how to filter the unavailable and restricted video,..

[Youtube Video on YOUTUBE search API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOEAD-gfJ_M)

Use a parameter format and restriction along with the youtube api endpoint

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=GoogleDevelopers&max-results=1&v=2.1&alt=jsonc&format=5&restriction=DE

If you hit this endpoint of youtube you can get a set of youtube videos which can be embedded as well as we can check whether the video is restricted in our locality.